# Permutation count for non identical letters

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Question: Find the number of permutations of letters of the word ’COMBINATORICS’ where $2$ consecutive letters are never identical.

What I have tried:

"COMBINATORICS" has $13$ characters with repeated elements $2$ "I", $2$ "O", and $2$ "C".

I know that $13!/2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ would give us the count of their combination. However, I am trying to get the count where no $2$ consecutive letters are identical.

Here is my attempt:

$\frac{13!}{2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!} - \left( \left(\frac{12!}{2!\cdot 2!}\right) + \right(\frac{12!}{2!\cdot 2!}\left) + \left(\frac{12!}{2!\cdot 2!}\right) \right)$

I used $12$ because I assumed the $2$ I to be as one unit so the total letters would be $12$ and so on for the rest. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  You did not however use [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) correctly.  Remember that $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$.

In our problem, let $I$ represent the set of arrangements where the two `I`'s were adjacent.  Let $O$ represent the set of arrangements where the two `O`'s were adjacent.  Let $C$ represent the set of arrangements where the two `C`'s were arrangement.  Let $\Omega$ represent the set of arrangements where we don't care.

We wish to count $|\Omega\setminus (I\cup O\cup C)|$ which simplifies:

$$|\Omega\setminus(I\cup O\cup C)|=|\Omega|-|I\cup O\cup C|$$

$$=|\Omega|-|I|-|O|-|C|+|I\cap O|+|I\cap C|+|O\cap C|-|I\cap O\cap C|$$

You correctly calculated $|\Omega|$ to be $\frac{13!}{2!2!2!}$ and you correctly calculated each of $|I|,|O|,|C|$ to be $\frac{12!}{2!2!}$, however you are missing the remainder of the terms.

Comment: Ahh alright thanks ;)